# app crashing due to not storing data in database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite

I dont know where m getting wrong here is the output of console

```
2011-10-07 11:03:29.508 Golden Corral[2365:207] After whole process Name : Ggggggggggg
2011-10-07 11:03:29.513 Golden Corral[2365:207] After whole process Score : 27600
2011-10-07 11:03:29.515 Golden Corral[2365:207] Error : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1660 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1660.)" UserInfo=0x5566d60 {NSValidationErrorObject=<HighScore: 0x5563eb0> (entity: HighScore; id: 0x5555ed0 <x-coredata:///HighScore/tDAD877F0-0594-4E14-819F-AF5BDA4A38A82> ; data: {
PlayerName = Ggggggggggg;
TopTenScore = 27600;
}), NSValidationErrorKey=PlayerName, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1660.), NSValidationErrorValue=Ggggggggggg}
```

and here is my code of saving data. I am checking whether the user enteres his name for highscore or not, if not m taking name Anonymous else what the user has entered. Gdb shows the correct value of both user name  and highScore but data is not storing in database.

```
    -(void)calculateHighScore
{

    //////////////////////////       Core Data  Entries.    ///////////////


    HighScore *ScoreData = (HighScore*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"HighScore" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];



    if ([txtName.text isEqualToString:@""] || [txtName.text length] == 0 )
    {



            NSLog(@"The Name :%@",txtName.text);

            NSLog(@"%d",CountHighScore);

            ScoreData.PlayerName = @"Anonymous";
            ScoreData.TopTenScore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:CountHighScore];

            NSLog(@"The Name :%@",ScoreData.PlayerName);

            NSLog(@"%d",CountHighScore);

            isWinner = NO;
            levelCount ++;




    }

    else 
    {



            NSLog(@"Befor Text assign highscore :%d",CountHighScore);

            //CountHighScore = [txtName.text intValue];

            ScoreData.PlayerName = txtName.text;
            ScoreData.TopTenScore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:CountHighScore];

            NSLog(@"The Name :%@",txtName.text);

            NSLog(@"%d",CountHighScore);


            isWinner = NO;
            levelCount ++;




    }

    NSLog(@"After whole process Name : %@",ScoreData.PlayerName);
    NSLog(@"After whole process Score : %d",CountHighScore);

    // Code for inserting into DataBase
    NSError *CorrectError;      
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&CorrectError])
    {
        // Handle the error...
        NSLog(@"Error : %@",CorrectError);
    }



}
```

Comment: What is type of `PlayerName`?

Comment: PlayerName is type of String and TopTenscore is Integer type.

Comment: Do add any validation functions on that property in your model file? Length?

Comment: yes I have set max length of Player name upto 8, it is not mandatory, should i remove it ?

Comment: Hey thanks, i remove the length and now it is running fine.

Comment: But i dint understand y this happened ???

Comment: I will move my comments to an answer. That may be helpful for someone else. Accept it, pls =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer was found during conversation in comments.*

When you are creating new key in your model you can set restrictions to the values of that property.

In current example restrictions were set on values of key `PlayerName`: maximum length of it was set to 8.

So when you set value of `PlayerName` key to `@"Ggggggggggg"` that has length more then 8 you will receive error when committing changes to the database. All restrictions are checked only after your have made all the changes to objects and want to save them to your database by committing changes.

Comment: cant I check it at run time and ask user to enter name less than 8 or if user enter more than 8 letters than only first 8 letters are acceptable ???

Comment: If user will enter more then 8 characters app will crash when saving that values to db. You should manually check length of input string and crop it if needful or decline its saving.